# AWS CDK, Unable to create ARM instance

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, arm, aws-cdk

I am using AWS CDK and I am trying to create ARM instance. This is the error I am getting:

`TypeError: latest_amazon_linux() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cpuType'`

This is the python code that I am trying to use:

```
    amzn_linux = ec2.MachineImage.latest_amazon_linux(
        cpuType=ec2.AmazonLinuxCpuType.ARM_64,
        generation=ec2.AmazonLinuxGeneration.AMAZON_LINUX_2,
        edition=ec2.AmazonLinuxEdition.STANDARD,
        virtualization=ec2.AmazonLinuxVirt.HVM,
        storage=ec2.AmazonLinuxStorage.GENERAL_PURPOSE
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

and to answer my own question:

```
    amzn_linux = ec2.MachineImage.latest_amazon_linux(
        generation=ec2.AmazonLinuxGeneration.AMAZON_LINUX_2,
        edition=ec2.AmazonLinuxEdition.STANDARD,
        virtualization=ec2.AmazonLinuxVirt.HVM,
        storage=ec2.AmazonLinuxStorage.GENERAL_PURPOSE,
        cpu_type=ec2.AmazonLinuxCpuType.ARM_64
        )
```